# how to fix "process system is not responding would you like to close it"

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run my program using android emulator 4.0.3 in eclipse, every time that emulator is started, emulator show this message :

> "process system is not responding would you like to close it",

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: post your code and logcat output

Comment: what are you doing in your onCreate() method. Can you put it here